# Code Aligment and Resharper 10 together in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I read of people using the extension "Code Aligment" and Resharper together. However I cannot find an option to prevent Reshparper from removing extra spaces in declarations.

Simplest case, this:

```
[Inject] public InputController       inputController { private get; set; }
[Inject] public ICommandFactory       commandFactory  { private get; set; }
[Inject] public NetworkMachineManager machineManager  { private get; set; }
```

always becomes this:

```
[Inject] public InputController inputController { private get; set; }
[Inject] public ICommandFactory commandFactory { private get; set; }
[Inject] public NetworkMachineManager machineManager { private get; set; }
```

is there any way to keep the alignment, but not loosing the other formatting features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the feature is not implemented in Resharper. I added it in their wishlist.